# XSLT count items in array

Tags: arrays, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to modify an XLST 1.0 file and I found that I can use an array like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="array">
    <Item>106</Item>
    <Item>107</Item>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Now I want to write an IF structure where i have a test on the amount of items in the array.

I'v tried this, but this isn't working:

```
<xsl:if test="count($array) = 0"></xsl:if>
```

Am I using the right approach for this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the count? See if it not zero? Do something between `<xsl:if ...>`and `</xsl:if>` ? What do you mean with "it is not working"? Please be more specific, edit the question nicely according to my questions

Comment: I have answered this the best way I could, but I am puzzled: if you are hard-coding the variable values into the stylesheet, why would you need to count the Items in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there are no "arrays" in XML.

Next, `count($array)` in your example will always return 1, because your variable contains a single parent node. To count the child `Item` nodes, you would need to use `count($array/Item)`.

However, that too would fail, because in XSLT 1.0 your variable contains a *result-tree-fragment* - and XSLT 1.0 can only count nodes in a *node-set*.

One solution is to turn the RTF into a node-set, using an extension function (which is supported by practically all XSLT 1.0 processors). For example, the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="array-rtf">
    <Item>106</Item>
    <Item>107</Item>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="array" select="exsl:node-set($array-rtf)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($array/Item)"/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>2</test>
```

---

Another option is to use an internal element instead of a variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<my:array>
    <Item>106</Item>
    <Item>107</Item>
</my:array>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(document('')/*/my:array/Item)"/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've used the first approach, and it's working as expected. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: There are native arrays as of XSLT 3.0: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#arrays